# Inner join on an insert to assure integrity

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I'm copying data from a table to an other one. I'm wondering what would be better to maintain data integrity and performance.

**Steps** :

1. copy data older than x days from log to archive
2. remove data from log if it exist in archive

**From**

```
INSERT INTO archive
    SELECT * FROM logs
    WHERE datediff(day, logs.timestamp, GetDate()) > @day

DELETE logsf FROM logs As logsf
    INNER JOIN archive as archivef ON logsf.uuid = archivef.uuid
    WHERE datediff(day, logsf.timestamp, GetDate()) > @jour
```

**To**

```
INSERT INTO archive
    SELECT * FROM logs
    WHERE datediff(day, logs.timestamp, GetDate()) > @day
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM archive
        WHERE datediff(day, logs.timestamp, GetDate()) > @day
    )


DELETE logsf FROM logs As logsf
    INNER JOIN archive as archivef ON logsf.uuid = archivef.uuid
    WHERE datediff(day, logsf.timestamp, GetDate()) > @jour
```

1. Is this a good thing to do to ensure you are not trying to insert already existing data in a table?
2. If my 2 original query are within a transaction, is my 2nd option pointless (and adding useless processing time)?

Which one would you use :

> Insert if not exist + Delete if exist  (independance)
>     or
>     Insert and delete if no error    (transaction)
>     or
>     combine both

and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SQL Server you can use the [output clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) to put the deleted items directly into the archive table:

```
DELETE logs
    OUTPUT deleted.* INTO archive
    WHERE datediff(day, timestamp, GetDate()) > @jour
```

Comment: Thanks, I went with this suggestion and ended up with a very short query :) (however, the syntax seems to be `DELETE logs   
  OUTPUT deleted.* INTO archives  
  FROM logs  
  WHERE datediff(day, logs.timestamp, GetDate()) > @jour` ( __output__ come before __from__))

Comment: Sorry. I have been doing too many merge statements and OUTPUT goes at the end of MERGE statements :/ The response has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with option 2 because it would be a faster process since the SQL is less complex.

I prefer the idea of wrapping it in a transaction so that a roll-back will occur in case of any errors.